# Visual Studio Code tab shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have encountered difficulty when I use tab (`<a>*4` and then `tab`) for multiple line of a tag or table tag, every time it gives me all `<a>` or `<table>` in horizontal line instead of vertical line:

```
<div class="signs">
    <a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a>
</div>
```

which give me no problem with div tag:

```
<div class="sample">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

It is really annoying me every time, does anyone know how to fix this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `settings.json`:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
  "output.inlineBreak": 1
}
```

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119088#issuecomment-811297787 why this is the preferred setting over `syntaxProfiles`.